# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ExponentSQLite.exec')

Tags: react-native, expo-sqlite

ive initiated a new react-native app using `npx init` where i transferred a code i was using on anothe react native app. this code uses react `expo-sqlite`. i installed expo-sqlite but when i run the app, i get this annoying error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ExponentSQLite.exec')
```

ive tried to update expo to latest version but the error still persists. i even deleted node-modules and re-installed using npm istall but it isnt working. how do i fix it? I'm running bare react-native which also uses some expo packages.

this is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";

const db = SQLite.openDatabase("silkyMarket.db");

export default class SQLiteScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todo: [],
      search: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // create user table if not exist
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        "create table if not exists tbl_register (id integer primary key not null, name text, contact text);"
      );
    });

    // check if registered
    const query = "select *from tbl_register";
    const array = [];

    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(query, array, (tx, results) => {
        this.setState({ todo: results.rows });
        console.log(this.state.todo._array);
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <Text>this is important</Text>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any Luck with this issue. I am facing the same on ios

Comment: Are you using expo development build or bare workflow? If yes, try to build your app again with expo-sqlite library. It seems like your development build does not contain the `expo-sqlite` library. Try to build it again.

more here: https://docs.expo.dev/development/build/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Expo bare workflow, you must delete the Android folder and run `expo run:android` again.

After these steps, the mentioned error stopped for me.